# Let $n \ge 5$. Show that, among the $s_n$ space parts, there are at least $(2n − 3)/4$ tetrahedra (HMO 1973)

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

[Engel's first problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMwCT.png)
[Engel's Second problem Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmG67.png)  (problems are from the Hungarian Mathematics Olympiad, 1973).

I'm having problems interpreting the last part of the proof on the second problem. I understand when Engel says that if the fifth plane intersects the line AB outside of the tetrahedron, as shown in figure 3.3, then there is a contradiction. But can't the fifth plane intersect the edge, for example, AC inside of the tetrahedron? Or in other words, the fifth plane intersects the tetrahedron ABCD into two regions. If that could occur then I don't see how there could be a contradiction, and that at most three planes can have a vertex on only one side. Furthermore, in this first part of the second problem, Engel's alludes to this problem. But then provides a contradiction by saying that this could not occur because then there would be a another point that is closer to the plane $\epsilon$.

Comment: H is for Hungarian (as can be verified from Engel's book, p. ix).

Comment: @RP_ Thanks. I'm sure I wasn't alone in not knowing that, since I don't have Engel's book and there was no link given besides the two pages.

Comment: The phrasing in Engel is a little weird, but the argument is correct. The key sentence is, "It cannot intersect all six edges of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ simultaneously." The fifth plane must intersect all six of the *lines* that are the edges of $ABCD$, but not all six of these intersections ("vertices") can occur along the *line segments* forming the tetrahedron. In your case one of these vertices must occur within the tetrahedron by assumption.  One must also occur outside of the tetrahedron. Then one of the faces of the tetrahedron has vertices on both sides, whence the contradiction.

Comment: In fact, one can show that at most four of the vertices can occur along the line segments, and this limit is realized.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot.